# Не работает ссылка в приложение

Tags: asp.net

После того как настроил webconfig для соединения с БД. Перестала работать ссылка на главной страницы. Когда я перехожу на страницу [Register.aspx](http://Register.aspx), просто возвращается строка в адресной строке http://localhost:4643/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fRegister.aspx. Причина, как мне кажется, кроется в данной строке настроек. Как мне решить мою проблему?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="Default.aspx" />
          </authentication>
```

Вот код моей страницы. Не работает ссылка с название "зарегистрироваться"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="webchat.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Вход в чат</h2>
    <p>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" 
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="10pt">
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </asp:Login>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                Авторизируйтесь пожалуйста или 
                <a href="Register.aspx">зарегистрируйтесь</a>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                Добро пожаловать, 
                <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />.<br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Войти в чат" NavigateUrl="~/Chat/Default.aspx"></asp:HyperLink><br/>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl="~/ChangePassword.aspx">Изменение пароля</asp:HyperLink>
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
    </p>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Login1"/>
    <p>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В web.config нужно разрешить неавторизованным пользователям доступ к странице `~/Register.aspx`:

```
<configuration> 
    ...
 <location path="~/Register.aspx">
      <system.web>
          <authorization>
               <allow users="*"/>
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
 </location>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, я не прав, но разве вместо `Register.aspx` не надо `~/Register.aspx` ?

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Register.aspx">зарегистрируйтесь</asp:HyperLink>
сделал так, только с HyperLink. Все равно мне выдает строку http://localhost:4643/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fRegister.aspx.